# Unable to log time entry using API

Tags: clockify

I am trying to log a time entry using the Clockify API. When I run the line below in my terminal I get the response that follows

```
curl -H 'content-type':'application/json' -H 'X-Api-Key':'api-key' -X POST https://api.clockify.me/api/workspaces/workspace-id/timeEntries/{"start": "2019-16-01T10:00:00" , "billable": "false" , "description": "Clockify API post" , "end": "2019-16-01T10:30:00"}/


curl: (3) [globbing] unmatched brace in column 77
curl: (3) Port number ended with ':'
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: ,
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: billable
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: false
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: ,
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: description
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: Clockify API post
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: ,
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: end
curl: (3) [globbing] unmatched close brace/bracket in column 20
```

Answer (score 0):

I generated the cURL code using Postman, and this is what it created:

```
curl -X POST \
  https://api.clockify.me/api/workspaces/workspace-id/timeEntries/ \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  -H 'X-Api-Key: value' \
  -H 'cache-control: no-cache' \
  -d '{"start": "2019-16-01T10:00:00" , "billable": "false" , "description": "Clockify API post" , "end": "2019-16-01T10:30:00"}'
```

I think you are missing the -d in front of the JSON - I think it might also need to be surrounded by '' (single quotation marks), but I'm not an expert at cURL so I can't say for sure.